# Memory Management in scalatest AnyFunSuite

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am trying to test a query streaming algorithm implemented in Scala over XML Files, using `AnyFunSuite` class.

I have 8 queries (`Q1-Q8`) ranging over 9 files (`F1-F9`). I created a test class for each query containing 9 tests, and a parent test class to run them all in sequence (9*8 = 72 tests) in the order `Q1` to `Q8` each from `F1` to `F9`. All execution times are logged using `Log4j`.

The main issue is that if I get different execution times as following (average of 5 runs and I am rounding the numbers for better interpretation) :

- `Q8` for `F9` coming as last in the full test (72 tests): `200 000 ms`
- `Q8` for `F9` coming as last in the Q8 query test (9 tests): `135 000 ms`
- `Q8` for `F9` coming as a standalone test (1 test): `106 000 ms`

This is the case for all tests and the real execution time would be for the standalone test. The difference factor is quite relevant, the more the test is ahead in the sequence, the more the execution time differs (`Q8-F8` is the worst case as the last test). My problem is to avoid running all tests as standalone manually (this the main purpose of automated tests!) but it seems the tests under the same thread/process share memory which is not cleaned properly after each test.

My need is how to approach this matter and run these tests in sequence but as if they are standalone (maybe cleaning the whole memory after each test), noting the tests are independent and do not share any data.

Update1: build.sbt file content

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

lazy val scalaTestVersion = "3.1.0"
lazy val akkaVersion = "2.6.10"
lazy val log4jVersion = "2.14.0"

lazy val run = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "p0",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % akkaVersion,
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion % Test,
      "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % scalaTestVersion,
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % "test",
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.1",
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % log4jVersion,
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % log4jVersion
    ),
    test in assembly := {},
    assemblyJarName in assembly := s"p0-$version.jar"
  )
  .dependsOn(p1, p2)

lazy val p1 = RootProject(file("../p1"))
lazy val p2 = RootProject(file("../p2"))
```

Comment: Do you have `Test / parallelExecution := false` on your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No not really, I updated the question with my build.sbt file

Comment: By default **ScalaTest** _(or it is **sbt**, I really do not know)_ runs the tests in parallel. So, that may be causing the issue. I would try adding that flag as well as updating to the lastest versions of everything _(since it may be a bug that was already fixed)_ like **sbt** to `1.4.5`, **Scala** to `2.13.4` and **ScalaTest** to `3.2.3`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I will test it, thank you

Comment: If your tests are not independent they are not tests.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I tried it but it did not fix it in a relatively

Comment: @TomerShetah The tests are independent in terms of objects and they do not share any variables and practically no side effects. My first intuition was the memory, I am assuming when a test in a sequence finishes, its objects are not garbage collected directly, then with the sequence moving on (within the same run like case 1 and 2 not standalone), swapping and paging is causing additional execution time. And I am not experienced enough on how to approach it.